# #pragma region in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, pragma

In the following program I wrote in C#:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            paramsAndOptionalTest(1,2);

#pragma region CmdLineStuff
            for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", args[i]);
            }
            foreach (string arg in args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(arg);
            }
            string[] apiargs = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();//this will give the executable name and path too
            int exitCode = Environment.ExitCode;
            foreach (string arg in apiargs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(arg);

            }
            Console.WriteLine("Exit Code {0}", exitCode);
            string myString = string.Format("11 in hexa is {0:x}", 11);
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(myString);

#pragma endregion CmdLineStuff
            ImmutableStrings();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

I used the [#pragma region](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6xkz944%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). But I am getting CS1633: Unrecognized #pragma directive warning.So I think C# compiler doesn't recognize this Pragma where as in C++ it worked fine.Is there any equivalent for this pragma in C#?

Comment: AFAIR it's simply `#region`

Comment: Besides the #region syntax please have a look at this question for information on good (and bad) use of regions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755465/do-you-say-no-to-c-sharp-regions

Comment: -1 for no own effort on finding the solution. First result of "C# region" entered in Google resolves the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is simply

```
#region CmdLineStuff
......
#endregion CmdLineStuff
```

The [docs could be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a1ybwek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and here there is the full documentation for the [C# Preprocessor directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx)

Comment: For the sake of completeness: the name of the region is not mandatory after the `#endregion` directive. Just a matter of style.